# Render mvc partial view by jquery select change event

Tags: jquery, html, model-view-controller

im trying to load a partial view into a div from my controller that has to parameters.
I already did similer code on a button click with one parameter and it worked. but its not working with the select .change.
I have two selects and two parameters in the controller. Im trying to figure out whats wrong?

```
public ActionResult MealandKcal(string searchString, double kcal)
        {
            Random rnd = new Random();

            var imgs = from a in _context.Images.Include("Restaurant").ToList()
                       orderby rnd.Next()
                       select a;


            var meals = from a in _context.Meals.Include("Image").ToList()
                        orderby rnd.Next()
                        select a;

            var meal = from a in meals
                       select a;

            if (kcal == 200)
            {
                meal = meal.Where(m => m.Name.Contains(searchString) && m.Calories < 200);
            }
            else if (kcal == 500)
            {
                meal = meal.Where(m => m.Name.Contains(searchString) && m.Calories >= 200 && m.Calories < 500);
            }
            else
            {
                meal = meal.Where(m => m.Name.Contains(searchString) && m.Calories >= 500);
            }

            RestaurantViewModel viewModel = new RestaurantViewModel()
            {
                Images = imgs,
                Meals = meal.ToList()
            };

            return PartialView(viewModel);

            }
```

Here are the two selects:

```
<div class="container">
            <p style="font-weight:700; margin-top:20px;">
                Or, filter both at the same time <i class="em em-sunglasses"></i>
            </p>
            <div class="row" style="text-align:center;">
                <div class="col-md-6 col-6">
                    <select id="category" class="form-control">
                        <option value="">Select Category</option>
                        <option value="Salad"><i class="em em-green_salad"></i> Salad</option>
                        <option value="Soup"><i class="em em-bowl_with_spoon"></i> Soup</option>
                        <option value="Spaghetti"><i class="em em-spaghetti"></i> Spaghetti</option>
                        <option value="Steak"><i class="em em-cut_of_meat"></i> Steak</option>
                        <option value="Beef"><i class="em em-meat_on_bone"></i> Beef</option>
                        <option value="Pizza"><i class="em em-pizza"></i> Pizza</option>
                        <option value="Chicken"><i class="em em-chicken"></i> Chicken</option>
                        <option value="Fish"><i class="em em-tropical_fish"></i> Fish</option>
                        <option value="Salmon"><i class="em em-fish"></i> Salmon</option>
                        <option value="Cookie"><i class="em em-cookie"></i> Cookie</option>
                        <option value="Potato"><i class="em em-potato"></i> Potato</option>
                        <option value="Sandwich"><i class="em em-sandwich"></i> Sandwich</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 col-6">
                    <select id="kcal" class="form-control">
                        <option value="">Select Calories range</option>
                        <option value="200">Less than 200 Kcal</option>
                        <option value="500">Less than 500 Kcal</option>
                        <option value="1000">More than 500 Kcal</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

and here is my jquery:

```
var url = '@Url.Action("MealandKcal", "Home")';
                            $('#category').change(function () {
                                var category = $(this).val();
                                $("#kcal").change(function () {
                                    var kcal = $(this).val();
                                    $("#querydiv").load(url, { searchText: category, kcal: kcal });
                                });
                            });
```

Comment: You have a typo in your first binding of the change event. Should be `.change()` and not `.chang`

Comment: nope i fixed it and nothing changed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bind the `onchange` event on both selects simultaneously. This allows you to apply logic within a single callback and run your conditionals before making a request.

Having a nested binding doesn't really accommodate your expectation here because it will only execute if the category select is changed AND THEN the kcal select.

Here's a revised snippet of your code.

- Bind `onchange` for both `#category` and `#kcal` selects
- When either are trigger, check to see if both have a value
- Fetch results if above statement is true

```js
var url = '@Url.Action("MealandKcal", "Home")';

// Bind onchange to both selects
$('#category, #kcal').on('change', function () {
  // Return category select value
  var categoryValue = $('select#category').val()
  // Return category select value
  var caloricValue = $('select#kcal').val()
  // If both selects have been changed, fetch results...
  if (categoryValue && caloricValue) {
    // debug
    console.log('fetch results');
    // Result query
    $("#querydiv").load(url, {
      searchText: categoryValue,
      kcal: caloricValue
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
    <p style="font-weight:700; margin-top:20px;">
        Or, filter both at the same time <i class="em em-sunglasses"></i>
    </p>
    <div class="row" style="text-align:center;">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-6">
            <select id="category" class="form-control">
                <option value="">Select Category</option>
                <option value="Salad"><i class="em em-green_salad"></i> Salad</option>
                <option value="Soup"><i class="em em-bowl_with_spoon"></i> Soup</option>
                <option value="Spaghetti"><i class="em em-spaghetti"></i> Spaghetti</option>
                <option value="Steak"><i class="em em-cut_of_meat"></i> Steak</option>
                <option value="Beef"><i class="em em-meat_on_bone"></i> Beef</option>
                <option value="Pizza"><i class="em em-pizza"></i> Pizza</option>
                <option value="Chicken"><i class="em em-chicken"></i> Chicken</option>
                <option value="Fish"><i class="em em-tropical_fish"></i> Fish</option>
                <option value="Salmon"><i class="em em-fish"></i> Salmon</option>
                <option value="Cookie"><i class="em em-cookie"></i> Cookie</option>
                <option value="Potato"><i class="em em-potato"></i> Potato</option>
                <option value="Sandwich"><i class="em em-sandwich"></i> Sandwich</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-6">
            <select id="kcal" class="form-control">
                <option value="">Select Calories range</option>
                <option value="200">Less than 200 Kcal</option>
                <option value="500">Less than 500 Kcal</option>
                <option value="1000">More than 500 Kcal</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it returned this error:
jquery-3.3.1.js:9600 POST http://localhost:65323/Home/MealandKcal 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: Internal Server Error is a server-side issue. Check your request params and go from there...

Comment: yes indeed the problem was in my parameters! Thank you very much you really helped :D :D